# freeradius radacct update occurs after another connection establishment

Tags: networking, openvpn, freeradius

sorry for my bad english.i connect via openvpn from my win7 client to freeradius server that is in the ubuntu os.my external database for authentication is ldap.i use mysql for freeradius accounting information.when user connected to freeradius server,one record with the correct acctstarttime is added to radacct but my problem is that when my user disconnect from win7,its acctstoptime remains null and after a period it is updated when another connection request from that user is sent to the radius server.disconnection time in are correct but my problem is its update time.

Answer (score 0):

there might be problem on your freeradius server time. check system time
use  date command